# Apache is not starting?

Tags: php, apache, port80

I am not able to start apache server(version 2.4) on my windows-64. I tried everything like changing the port from 80 to 81 or 8080. And I also looked into my services, not even a single service, using 80 port(like skype, IIS or Webclient).

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You installed apache separately or as apart of WAMP/XAMP??

Comment: Look in Event Viewer / System log.

Comment: not only services use port :) execute this command `netstat -a -b`